# Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to build a list where each item contains an icon on the far side. However, when I try and access the list when more than one item is added I get the error:
`Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1`

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './images.dart';

class LikedList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LikedListState createState() => _LikedListState();
}

class _LikedListState extends State<LikedList> {
  static List<bool> _likes = List.filled(ImagesState.likes.length,true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Liked List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
        itemCount: ImagesState.likes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = ImagesState.likes[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(item),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: _likes[index]
                  ? Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_border,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  : Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  print(_likes);
                  _likes[index] = !_likes[index];
                  print(_likes);
                });
              },
            ),
            onLongPress: () {
              setState(() {
                print(ImagesState.likes[index]);
                ImagesState.likes.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Similar suggestions point to `itemCount` not being set, but I am using that.

Comment: when you are facing this one? what action you are performing

Comment: What's there in `ImagesState.likes` ? Possibly you can set `itemCount` value equals to `_likes.length`.

Comment: @Purvik Rana If I set it to `_likes.length`, after accessing the list for the first time, even if more items are added, they are not shown in the list. `ImagesState.likes` is in another file and is a fixed array of 5 items.

Comment: @jitsm555: here is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXKfx.gif

Comment: I just checked your gif. It's range error related to list that you're accessing. Please check once where you're adding the item and if after adding item your list is actually having it or not.

Comment: I have tested and I can see the item is correctly being added to the list

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be creating a fixed length list with the statement:

```
static List<bool> _likes = List.filled(ImagesState.likes.length,true);
```

That will create a filled fixed length list of length .likes.length, containing values 'true'.
You need to add a third parameter 'growable: true' in your method call to be able to add to the list.

Comment: Thanks the the reply, I added 'growable':
`static List<bool> _likes = List.filled(ImagesState.likes.length,true, growable: true);`
But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please show the line of code that the error occurs at.

Comment: Here is the stack trace:
`When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:146:60)
#1      _LikedListState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:sosam/likedlist.dart:26:27)
#2      new ListView.separated.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:1083:34)
#3      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:446:22)
#4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1134:67)`

Line 26:
`icon: _likes[index]`

Comment: I can only suggest that you set some breakpoints and check what index is going to and the actual length of ImagesState.likes.length.